# Returning out of void method from nested method

Tags: c#

If I have a void method I can do something like this to break out of it early

```
public void CheckIntNotLessThanZero(int value)
{
    if (int < 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Not less than zero!")
}
```

However I run that exact same check several times and so I want to put it into its own method so I don't repeat code:

```
public void CheckIntNotLessThanZero(int value)
{
    return CheckIntValue(value);

    Console.WriteLine("Not less than zero!")
}

public void CheckIntValue(int value)
{
    if (value < 0)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

That's a basic example but is there a way to do this?

Comment: what problem are you facing?

Comment: @TechieBee: it looks like OP wants to interrupt method execution (`CheckIntNotLessThanZero` in the sample) in the case, when one of the conditions failed.

Comment: @Dennis - Oh..Thanks..now i get it !!

Answer (score 7):

Turn your `Check...` methods to return `bool` value, and check it after every call:

```
public bool CheckIntValue(int value)
{
    return value < 0;
}

public void CheckIntNotLessThanZero(int value)
{
    if (CheckIntValue(value))
        return;

    Console.WriteLine("Not less than zero!")
}
```

Note, that you *could* throw exceptions in `Check...` methods, but you *must not*. To manage execution flow using exceptions is a bad practice.

Comment: Could I just do `return CheckIntValue(value)` as in your example?

Comment: You can't. `CheckIntNotLessThanZero` returns `void`, `CheckIntValue` - `bool`. This even won't compile.